# shell script, What happens when you use '-o' option and only one variable?

Tags: bash, shell

For example, when you run the following shell script:

```
foo="example"


if [ -o $foo ]; then
        foo="true"
        echo $foo

fi
```

The result is false and nothing is returned.

but If the value of foo is null

```
foo=" "


if [ -o $foo ]; then
        foo="true"
        echo $foo

fi
```

Returns true value.

The operation foo = "example" if [ $foo -o $foo ] in shell scripts is understandable.(I understand that the value is true.)

However, if foo = "abc" if [ -o $foo ], I understand it as null or true ($foo value).

The result is false, contrary to my expectation.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Docs say `In particular, only expressions containing -a, -o, ( or ) can be ambiguous.`. Why would you use an OR operator with only one element?

Comment: `test -o` == `test -n "-o"` == true. But _really_, the parts of [the POSIX spec for `test`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) where it says nobody should ever use `-o` or `-a` in modern code are worth paying attention to. (In reading that specification, look for the `[OB]` tags; they mark "obsolescent" behaviors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some facts:

- In bash, `-o` in `[ -o OPTION ]` is an operator to test if shell option OPTION is enabled.
- `[ STRING ]` tests if STRING is not empty.
- Inside **single brackets (`[ ]`)**, if `$foo` is unquoted it undergoes [**word splitting**](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).

So:

- For `foo=' '; [ -o $foo ]` the test executed is `[ -o ]`. `-o` is not an empty string so it returns **true**.
- `opt=posix; set -o $opt; [ -o $opt ]` returns true, because the option `posix` is set.
- `opt=posix; set +o $opt; [ -o $opt ]` returns false, because the option `posix` is unset.

**In double bracket test syntax, word splitting does not occur**. So in `foo=' '; [[ -o $foo ]]` the space is *preserved*. The test executed is `[[ -o <space> ]]`, which returns **false**, because <space> (a literal space) is not an an enabled shell option.

I recommend using double brackets unless you have a good reason not too. Single bracket test syntax is mainly for compatibility with POSIX and legacy bourne shell scripts.

If you use single brackets, quote all variables to prevent word splitting and glob expansion (which does not occur inside double brackets).

Answer (score 0):

Reading the bash source code:

**Case 1a:** `foo="example"; [ -o $foo ]` → `[ -o example ]`

**Case 1b:** `foo=""; [ -o "$foo" ]` → `[ -o □ ]`

- using  □ to denote that argument is empty string
- parsed as [two arguments](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/test.c#L822)
- first argument (`-o`) matches [unary operator](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/test.c#L753) "[find_option_o_value](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/test.c#L622)"
- second argument is not a [valid option name](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/builtins/set.def#L266)
- result: false (not found)

  - **note:** when second argument *is* a valid option name, the return value will indicate if the option is set (true ⇒ enabled, false ⇒ disabled)

**Case 2a:** `foo=" "; [ -o $foo ]` → `[ -o ]`

**Case 2b:** `foo=" "; [ $foo -o $foo ]` → `[ -o ]`

- parsed as [one argument](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/test.c#L817)
- argument (`-o`) is [non-null](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/test.c#L768)
- result: true

**Case 3:** `foo=""; [ "$foo" -o "$foo" ]` → `[ □ -o □ ]`

- using □ to denote that argument is empty string
- parsed as [three arguments](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/test.c#L827)
- second argument is [ANDOR](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/test.c#L780) operator
- neither first nor third argument is [non-null](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/test.c#L785)
- result: false

**Case 4:** `foo=""; [ "$foo" -o $foo ]` → `[ □ -o ]`

- using □ to denote that argument is empty string
- parsed as [two arguments](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/test.c#L822)
- first argument is not a unary operator
- result: false (syntax error)

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you don't quote a variable, and the variable is empty, or only white space (what is in $IFS), the command doesn't see that at all. so test -o $foo is the same as test -o

I don't think there's a particularly good reason it returns true, what you have done is pathological and makes no sense. What you need to do is double quote the variable, that guarantees that test can see there is something there, and then it will do something rational with it. As a general rule, always double quote stuff that you pass to test, just in case it is empty.

Comment: There is a good reason that `test -o` returns 0.  Namely, `-o` is not the empty string.

Comment: -o is not testing itself, it is supposed to test something else, which in this case doesn't exist. I actually think 0 is irrational because normally when testing OR conditions, you start from FALSE, and then become TRUE only when you find such a TRUE condition. But if there are zero conditions, the result should be FALSE. In contrast, if you are doing AND, you start from the TRUE condition and any FALSE condition changes it to FALSE.

Comment: That may be your intuition, but test does not work that way.  If there is only one argument, test merely checks to see if that argument is the empty string. This is certainly a foible, or a mis-design, or a terrible bug, but changing the behavior would break millions of lines of existing code. Behavior like this is why many people recommend avoiding test completely.

Comment: @WilliamPursell That's not what test is doing in this case. If you use -o, and there is only one argument, then that argument is of course... -o. So it's not "testing" -o at all. -o tests something that comes before and after -o.  Why it returns true in this case, is just a foible.